# query muliple fields with multiple values

Tags: ms-access, vb6

i need a query that will do a dictionary like lookup in an ms-access database with vb6. The database contains a table and two fields A & B.

for example if A contains 1,2,3,4,5,6 and the corresponding values in B is a,b,c,d,e,f

then i will pass values 1,4,6 to the query, and it should return a,d,f

somthing like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE A = 1 and 2 and 6`

Comment: Is this a lookup table? Or have you failed to create one? What's the real data? You seemed to have boiled it down to a state of simplicity that makes it look inane (i.e., not something you'd ever want to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are doing just one at a time then your query could look like this

SELECT B from table WHERE A=5

This would return the value in field B that relates when column A is 5

If you want to return multiple values then you could do this

SELECT A,B FROM table WHERN A IN(1,3,6,7)

This would return multiple values, you could then load those into an array and search for the value you want

Comment: thanks, but this will not work. for each batch values i supply, i need corresponding values in field B. so for field values A of (1,3,6), i need field values B (A,C,F) returned accordingly. any values not found will return blank or null string

Comment: Is this not what I described in example 2? You pass it a load of values (1,3,6,7) and it returns a recordset with both fields returned so the first row would have 1,A the second row would have 3,C the third row would have 6,F and so on. You can then either search through this recordset or load it up into an array for later use

Comment: (A, B) touple contains ('1,2,3,4,5,6', 'a,b,c,d,e,f') on first row and ('7,8', 'g,h') on second one for instance.

Comment: if it possible i return both the values passed with the result.